# How to convert this classs component to function component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to convert this class to a function but it fails:

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  state = { settings: [{ id: "1", open: false }, { id: "2", open: false }] };

  handleClick = id => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      settings: state.settings.map(item => item.id === id ? { ...item, open: !item.open } : item
      )
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { settings } = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={{ marginRight: "15px" }}>
        <core.List component="nav">
          {myData.map(each => (
            <React.Fragment key={each.id}>
              <core.ListItem button onClick={() => this.handleClick(each.id)}>
                <core.ListItemText inset primary={each.nameHeader} />
                {settings.find(item => item.id === each.id).open
                  ? "expanded"
                  : "collapsed"}
              </core.ListItem>
              <core.Divider />
              <core.Collapse
                in={settings.find(item => item.id === each.id).open}
                timeout="auto"
                unmountOnExit
              >
                <core.List component="div" disablePadding>
                  {each.subMenu.map(subData => (
                    <core.ListItem key={subData.id} button>
                      <core.ListItemText inset primary={subData.name} />
                    </core.ListItem>
                  ))}
                </core.List>
              </core.Collapse>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
        </core.List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MyClass;
```

Used to use mui (old version):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as core from "@material-ui/core";
import { myData } from "./myData";
```

I want to open and close each item separately when mapping.

It does not execute when it becomes a function, or I did not convert it correctly! 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you would want to convert `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` to a `useEffect`, and all state variables to a `useState`. Also, you don't need `this.`.

#### In your case:

```
import {useState} from 'react'

const MyClass = props => {
  const [settings, setSettings] = useState([{ id: "1", open: false }, { id: "2", open: false }])

  handleClick = id => {
    setSettings(oldSettings => (
       oldSettings.map(item => item.id === id ? { ...item, open: !item.open } : item)
    );
  };

    return (
      <div style={{ marginRight: "15px" }}>
        <core.List component="nav">
          {myData.map(each => (
            <React.Fragment key={each.id}>
              <core.ListItem button onClick={() => handleClick(each.id)}>
                <core.ListItemText inset primary={each.nameHeader} />
                {settings.find(item => item.id === each.id).open
                  ? "expanded"
                  : "collapsed"}
              </core.ListItem>
              <core.Divider />
              <core.Collapse
                in={settings.find(item => item.id === each.id).open}
                timeout="auto"
                unmountOnExit
              >
                <core.List component="div" disablePadding>
                  {each.subMenu.map(subData => (
                    <core.ListItem key={subData.id} button>
                      <core.ListItemText inset primary={subData.name} />
                    </core.ListItem>
                  ))}
                </core.List>
              </core.Collapse>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
        </core.List>
      </div>
    );
}
export default MyClass;
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')

Comment: I can't possibly know why `settings.find(item => item.id === each.id)` is undefined without knowing the contents.